# Cannot read a device's serial number when SELinux runs in enforcing mode

Tags: android, selinux

I developed a native application for Android 12 which needs access to the system property `ro.boot.serialno`. As the application is part of a release ROM, SELinux runs in enforcing mode.
Due to this, during runtime I get AVC errors such as:

```
type=1400 audit(0.0:13): avc: denied { read } for name="u:object_r:serialno_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=17845 scontext=u:r:my_service:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:serialno_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
```

and as a consequence, my application cannot obtain the serial number of the device.

According to [domain.te](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/sepolicy/+/master/public/domain.te#554), this property can only be accessed by a few allowed domains. After reading the documentation and experimenting several SELinux rules, I didn't succeed in overcoming the problem.

I already tried adding `allow myservice serialno_prop:file read;` to the .te file of my application. But during compile time the build system complains that it goes against the `neverallow` rule defined in the file above (in line 554).

I also tried adding `get_prop(my_service, serialno_prop)` to the .te file, but it also does not work.

So my questions are: What instructions should be added to SELinux files so that my application can properly read `ro.boot.serialno`? As a side question, is it possible to extend a `neverallow` policy? If so, what is the proper way of doing it?